# What should an s3 end point look like when configuring an ALIAS record in Route53?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm trying to point my root domain to an s3 bucket that redirects to www.mywebsite.com. However, when I try to configure my ALIAS record to point an s3 endpoint, the only endpoint that the dialogue offers me is:

`s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

It seems an awful lot like this value should be

`mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

When I try to change it to this though, Route53 tells me it's an invalid value. Here's a screenshot of the pop up I'm getting.

[image]

Could this possibly be right? Has anyone seen this before/know of a way to fix it if not? All thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are aliasing to an endpoint, not your specific resource.

s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com is the correct value, assuming your bucket lives in us stanard region.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-switch-to-route53-as-dnsprovider